# Black Diamonds that are Fixing themselves in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am running into a very strange issue with a site that I am working on. The site is basically a job board where the owner or users can create job listings including a description that ends up being stored into a MySQL text field. What we are experiencing is this, whenever listings from certain sources are entered, they initially end up with the "Black Diamond" with a question mark inside character in place of apostrophes and double spaces. This part I know is an encoding issue and can correct. The real question is this, these black diamonds show when the record is displayed in a MySQL admin tool and when the job listing is viewed in a web browser (simple select statement displays the listing in a PHP app), but after the first time it is viewed, then the problem somehow fixes itself. It is like the running the select then displaying the record updates the job description field and fixes the encoding issues. How could this be? Has anyone ever heard of this or anything similar? I cannot understand how a database field would change without running an update statement...

Answer (score 2):

How are the job listings entered? Are they entered via a web page? If so, what character encoding does the web page use? (This should determine the character encoding of the submitted data AFAIK.) What character set is the connection used to communicate with MySQL? What is the character set of the column the data is stored in? Finally, what is the character encoding of the web page(s) on which the entered data is reviewed?

Here is what I do: I declare all of my pages as UTF-8 encoded, using the following tag at the start of the `<head>` section:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

I issue the following command immediately when I connect to MySQL, so as to make sure that MySQL understands the data I send to it will be UTF-8 encoded:

```
SET NAMES uft8
```

(Depending on the database abstraction method you use, a special function might be recommended in order to set the connection character set, like mysqli's `mysqli_set_charset()`.)

I also make sure that those columns in which I intend to store UTF-8 data are declared to be UTF-8. You can find out what the character set of a column is by issuing `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name`. The character set of the table (which by default is the character set for any column in the table) is displayed at the end. If the character set for the column is different to the default character set for the table then it is displayed as part of the column definition. If you wish to change the character set of a column then you can do so using `ALTER TABLE`.

If you have not previously taken the steps to handle character sets in your app then you may find that the tables are all using the `latin1` character set. If you naively store UTF-8-encoded data (for example) into these columns, you may run into character encoding issues. Changing the column character set using `ALTER TABLE` does not necessarily fix your old data, because MySQL reads your old data assuming it to be valid `latin1`-encoded text and converts it to the eqivalent UTF-8 (correctly converting what it has read, but not giving the result you want).

The above steps would hopefully mean that future data will be correctly encoded and correctly displayed, but you may have data already mis-encoded in your database, so be aware that if you follow the above steps and still see older data displaying incorrectly, this may be why. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Run into this problem a few years ago... I remember finding those notorious characters, and replacing them in php with a single quote or a double quote... Ofcourse with escaping... A simple preg_replace for those characters will do the trick... Its just an encoding issue...

Answer (score 0):

This page, though geared for wordpress might help

http://codex.wordpress.org/Converting_Database_Character_Sets

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (mysql encoding and webpage encoding set to UTF-8 but black diamonds showing up in my query results. I found this snippet while googling but cannot for the life of me find its source to give proper attribution:

```
if( function_exists('mysql_set_charset') ){
  mysql_set_charset('utf8', $db_connection);
}else{
  mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $db_connection);
}
```

Anyway, it cleared up the issue for me.